# I filled out W-9 in 2 different states for online buisness

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, w9

Can I have W-9 forms one in Texas and one in Puerto Rico at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You'd be completing the W-9 for whoever is requesting it (you don't send it to the IRS), so everything should be exactly the same regardless of who you're giving it to.

Exceptions to the forms being the same include: if you're issuing W-9s for different businesses you own (business info might be different), or if your business has multiple locations and you use the address most relevant to the requester.